# jQuery: how does this simple snippet work (dropdown)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, this

Code:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/ttbvqa0z/
- [original source](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) (#Example 2)

Generally, what do I understand so far is that
(but still I'd like to know if it's true or not):

- `var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );` is self-executing function (jQuery
  style)
- `var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );` executes function `DropDown(el)`
- `el` in that case is equal to `#dd`
- `this.dd = el` is equal to `#dd.dd = #dd`
- `this.initEvents()` is inherited from function's prototype, therefore it can be executed by the `dd` object

**Questions:**

- Why is there and what's the purpose of `var obj = this`? (in prototype)
- What's the `this` referring to?
  (I suppose it's saved reference so it's not being executed everytime but I don't know what that prototype's `this` is referring to)
- Why is there `obj.dd.on`?
  (`#dd.#dd.on`?)
- If function inherits prototype's proporties then why it's not valid to use following: `obj.dd = el` instead of `this.dd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest here we do not need to keep the this.

First this ( obj = this) referring to the Dropdown obj whereas **this** inside the click event referring to the jquery obj $('#dd') or obj.dd.

[enter link description here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/)

Comment: Oh! It's `dd.initEvents();` !
`var obj = this` references to the object `dd`.

So what we've got in `obj.dd.on` is `obj = dd` and its property `dd` which is equal to `$('#dd')` (declared here: `this.dd = el;`). My head is spinning.